# How to add vertex or point geometry in webgl scene using three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am new to webgl and three.js so don't have much knowledge about it.
Can anybody tell me how to add vertex or point geometry in webgl scene using three.js?

Comment: Might I recommend looking at the introductory examples at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for creating a triangular geometry from scratch.

```
var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(100,   0,   0) );
geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0, 100,   0) );
geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0,   0, 100) );
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2) );
geo.computeFaceNormals();
geo.computeVertexNormals();
```

Hope this helps!